# Better performance for running this query

Tags: sql-server

I want to improve the performance for running the following SQL.
Apparently its taking up 3.28 minutes to run 784 for the following query,
is there a better practice, or better solution to improve the performance of the code? Thanks so much

I've tried with Sum, Count, pivot and looks like Count is faster

```
    with Accounts as
    (select ID,displayName AccountName from u3_system.dbo.account with(nolock) 
    where 
        ID = '0439b9d9-f2c9-43dc-aa2d-08cdea94db21' 
        or ID = 'f815d2dd-e118-4930-a67d-08cf28b410e2'
        or ID = 'f606fcab-dcbd-4d02-8161-08d635cd8971'
        or ID = '7d8f44d4-0f17-41f1-87e2-08cf28b4343b'),

    Campaign as
    (select C.ID, Accounts.AccountName,C.displayName [Mailout Folder] from Accounts 
    left join u3_mail.dbo.Campaign C with(nolock) 
    on C.listID = Accounts.ID),

    mo as
    (select 
        campaign.AccountName
        ,campaign.[Mailout Folder]
        ,mo.ID [MailOutID]
        ,mo.displayName [Mailout Name]
        ,[date] [Send Date]
        ,Details.value('(//content)[1]/subject[1]', 'varchar(200)') AS [Subject Line]
    from campaign 
    inner join [u3_mail].[dbo].[mailout] mo WITH(NOLOCK)
    on mo.campaignID = campaign.ID),

    ML as
    (select mailoutID,
        count(mailoutId) [Total Messages],
        count(case when status = 'Delivered' then 1 else null end) Delivered,
        count(case when status <> 'Delivered' then 1 else null end) Undelivered,
        count(case when ReadDate is not null then 1 else null end) [Read],
        count(case when HasClicked = '1' then 1 else null end) [Unique Clicks],
        count(case when BounceDate is not null then 1 else null end) [Bounced],
        count(case when OptOutDate is not null then 1 else null end) [Opted Out]
    from 
        [u3_data].[data].[MailLog_0439b9d9f2c943dcaa2d08cdea94db21] ML with(nolock)
    group by MailoutID

    union

    select mailoutID,
        count(mailoutId) [Total Messages],
        count(case when status = 'Delivered' then 1 else null end) Delivered,
        count(case when status <> 'Delivered' then 1 else null end) Undelivered,
        count(case when ReadDate is not null then 1 else null end) [Read],
        count(case when HasClicked = '1' then 1 else null end) [Unique Clicks],
        count(case when BounceDate is not null then 1 else null end) [Bounced],
        count(case when OptOutDate is not null then 1 else null end) [Opted Out]
    from 
        [u3_data].[data].[MailLog_f815d2dde1184930a67d08cf28b410e2] ML with(nolock)
    group by MailoutID

    union

    select mailoutID,
        count(mailoutId) [Total Messages],
        count(case when status = 'Delivered' then 1 else null end) Delivered,
        count(case when status <> 'Delivered' then 1 else null end) Undelivered,
        count(case when ReadDate is not null then 1 else null end) [Read],
        count(case when HasClicked = '1' then 1 else null end) [Unique Clicks],
        count(case when BounceDate is not null then 1 else null end) [Bounced],
        count(case when OptOutDate is not null then 1 else null end) [Opted Out]
    from 
        [u3_data].[data].[MailLog_f606fcabdcbd4d02816108d635cd8971] ML with(nolock)
    group by MailoutID

    union

    select mailoutID,
        count(mailoutId) [Total Messages],
        count(case when status = 'Delivered' then 1 else null end) Delivered,
        count(case when status <> 'Delivered' then 1 else null end) Undelivered,
        count(case when ReadDate is not null then 1 else null end) [Read],
        count(case when HasClicked = '1' then 1 else null end) [Unique Clicks],
        count(case when BounceDate is not null then 1 else null end) [Bounced],
        count(case when OptOutDate is not null then 1 else null end) [Opted Out]
    from 
        [u3_data].[data].[MailLog_7d8f44d40f1741f187e208cf28b4343b] ML with(nolock)
    group by MailoutID
    ),

    ME as
    (select MailoutID,
        count(case when [Event] = 'LinkClicked' then 1 else null end) [Total Clicks],
        count(case when [Event] = 'AbuseReport' then 1 else null end) [Mark as Spam]
    from 
        [u3_data].[data].[MailEvent_0439b9d9f2c943dcaa2d08cdea94db21] ME with(nolock)
        inner join [u3_data].[data].[MailLog_0439b9d9f2c943dcaa2d08cdea94db21] ML with(nolock)
        on ML.ID = ME.messageID
        where [Event] in ('LinkClicked','AbuseReport')
    group by MailoutID

    union

    select MailoutID,
        count(case when [Event] = 'LinkClicked' then 1 else null end) [Total Clicks],
        count(case when [Event] = 'AbuseReport' then 1 else null end) [Mark as Spam]
    from 
        [u3_data].[data].[MailEvent_f815d2dde1184930a67d08cf28b410e2] ME with(nolock)
        inner join [u3_data].[data].[MailLog_f815d2dde1184930a67d08cf28b410e2] ML with(nolock)
        on ML.ID = ME.messageID
        where [Event] in ('LinkClicked','AbuseReport')
    group by MailoutID

    union

    select MailoutID,
        count(case when [Event] = 'LinkClicked' then 1 else null end) [Total Clicks],
        count(case when [Event] = 'AbuseReport' then 1 else null end) [Mark as Spam]
    from 
        [u3_data].[data].[MailEvent_f606fcabdcbd4d02816108d635cd8971] ME with(nolock)
        inner join [u3_data].[data].[MailLog_f606fcabdcbd4d02816108d635cd8971] ML with(nolock)
        on ML.ID = ME.messageID
        where [Event] in ('LinkClicked','AbuseReport')
    group by MailoutID

    union

    select MailoutID,
        count(case when [Event] = 'LinkClicked' then 1 else null end) [Total Clicks],
        count(case when [Event] = 'AbuseReport' then 1 else null end) [Mark as Spam]
    from 
        [u3_data].[data].[MailEvent_7d8f44d40f1741f187e208cf28b4343b] ME with(nolock)
        inner join [u3_data].[data].[MailLog_7d8f44d40f1741f187e208cf28b4343b] ML with(nolock)
        on ML.ID = ME.messageID
        where [Event] in ('LinkClicked','AbuseReport')
    group by MailoutID)


    select 
        mo.AccountName [Account Name]
        ,mo.[Mailout Folder]
        ,mo.[Mailout Name]
        ,mo.[Send Date]
        ,mo.[Subject line]
        ,ml.[Total Messages]
        ,ml.Delivered
        ,ml.Undelivered
        ,ml.[Read]
        ,ml.Delivered - ml.[Read] [Unread]
        ,ml.[Unique Clicks]
        ,me.[Total Clicks]
        ,ml.[Bounced]
        ,ml.[Opted Out]
        ,me.[Mark as Spam]
    from mo
    left join ml 
    on ml.mailoutID = mo.mailoutID
    left join me
    on me.mailoutID = ml.mailoutID
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without the execution plan, table schemas and indexes. The only advice one can give is to **remove NOLOCK**. This means `don't respect locks, read dirty or even duplicate data while taking excessive locks`

Comment: What are all those MailEvent and MailLog tables? If there's no chance of duplicate MailoutID values you can convert `UNION` to `UNION ALL`. `UNION` eliminates duplicates by performing a `DISTINCT` operation which involves sorting the results before identifying duplicates

Comment: One improvement, although it'll be ugly, could be to limit each query in the unions to only retrieve those with the mailoutID from the "mo" CTE.  But in SQL-Server, CTE's sometimes behave like a template, so putting the "mo" first in a temporary table and use that to link could prove faster.